# Who entered the Directive 4?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987

In the 1987 Robocop movie, when Robocop goes to arrest **"Dick Jones,"** Robocop was malfunctioning because of Directive 4. So my question is, who in OCP entered this directive into Robocop's systems without anybody knowing, and did **"Bob Morton"** know about Directive 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dick Jones was the author of Directive 4. From [the script](http://www.awesomefilm.com/script/robocop-script.pdf), after

> Robocop attempts to arrest Dick Jones,

Dick Jones says,

> What's the matter, officer? I'll tell you what's the matter. It's a little insurance policy called Directive 4<sup>1</sup>... **My little contribution to your psychological profile.** Any attempt to arrest a senior officer of OCP<sup>2</sup> results in shutdown...

I do not recall any evidence of Bob Morton knowing that Directive 4 even existed. Quite the contrary: when Morton asks Robocop to list is Prime Directives, Robocop lists the first three only.

[image: Directives 1 to 3]]

On his internal screen he sees:

> Directive 4: [Classified].

[image: Directive 4]]

Here's the scene:

<sub>1 The script wrongly calls it "Directive 3".</sub>

<sub>2 The script wrongly calls it "CMI".</sub>